# Percentage stored as a fraction of 1: What is this called?

Tags: terminology, fractions, percentages

I have a column in a database table called `CONDITION_PERCENT`.

It has values like:

- 1
- 0.1
- 0.01

Which are meant to represent:

- 100%
- 10%
- 1%

---

I suspect that referring to these values as *percentages* might be **incorrect**. Calling them *percentages* certainly seems to be misleading my users (everyone expects the values to be fractions of 100, not fractions of 1).

What is the proper name for percentage values that are a fraction of 1?

Comment: Is it possible to add another column -- one that contains genuine percentages, and another that contains, say, `percent_over_100` ?

Comment: @pjs36 Interesting idea. I could do this in a query, but I think it would be a bad practice to store calculated values in the table (we don't like to store redundant columns in the database world).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the decimal representation of a percent. A percent is always `/100` that's literally what it means, *"per cent"*. Or part per hundred. For 57%,

- The decimal representation is `0.57`
- The fractional representation is `57/100`

Note there are things that are parts per for different units,

- part per thousand (ppt) permille, symbol ‰
- part per ten thousand, permyriad ,symbol ‱
- part per hundred thousand (ppm), per cent mille.

And the list goes on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parts-per_notation#Thousand

Comment: You didn't say anything wrong, but also didn't really answer the question. Your answer suggests that it's ok to call it "percent", but 0.57 per cent is 0.0057 per one. Note that you wouldn't say "an hour is just 3600 seconds, so you can as well name the variable that holds hours `seconds`". The unit matters, otherwise you could just call all variables `float`.

Comment: @kca 0.57 is 57 per cent (%) while 0.0057 would be 0.57 per cent, or 57 (‱) permyriad.

Answer (score 2):

A proportion. It usually takes values between $0$ and $1$.